# Can we toggle values in Twig loops

Tags: twig

when including a twig file for lets say to display a 2 column layout having an image on one side and copytext on the other, the designers often ask to switch the image position each new row. So in the first row the image is on the left side, in the second row it's on the right side and so on.
I use to pass some flag to the included Twig file by counting a value up `image_orientation_count` and depending if it's odd or not pass a value to the Twig template like this:

```
{% set image_orientation_count = 1 %}
{% for mw_id in post.modeteaser_list %}

{% set teaser = TimberPost(mw_id) %}

{% if image_orientation_count is odd %}
    {% set image_orientation = 'left' %}
{% else %}
    {% set image_orientation = 'right' %}
{% endif %}

{% include 'templates/blocks/section-image-wide-text-small.twig' with {'title': teaser.title, 'copytext': teaser.copytext, 'mood_image': teaser.mood_image, 'button_url': teaser.button_url, 'button_label': teaser.button_label, 'image_orientation': image_orientation } only %}
{% set image_orientation_count = image_orientation_count + 1 %}

{% endfor %}
```

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to solve that kind of problems. Somehow the way I use to do it feels "cheap" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you:

```
{% for mw_id in post.modeteaser_list %}

    {% set teaser = TimberPost(mw_id) %}
    {% set image_orientation = loop.index is odd ? 'left' : 'right' %}

    {% include 'templates/blocks/section-image-wide-text-small.twig' with {
    'title': teaser.title, 
    'copytext': teaser.copytext, 
    'mood_image': teaser.mood_image, 
    'button_url': teaser.button_url, 
    'button_label': teaser.button_label, 
    'image_orientation': image_orientation 
    } only %}

{% endfor %}
```

with [`loop.index`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) and **ternary conditional operator,**

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was hoping for somehow!

Comment: :) Happy for you and thks for your return

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the [`cycle`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html) function like this:

```
{% for ... %}
{% include "foo.twig" with {
  "image_orientation": cycle(["left", "right"], loop.index0)
} only %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Maerlyn: I did not know the cycle function, so thank you +1 :)